# javascript image gallery with adjusted navigation for mobile platforms

Tags: mobile, navigation, image-gallery

I want to make a javascript image gallery 
(with 6 thumbnails in a row and as many rows as fit the page.
clicking the thumbnails will bring up a popup box with images and a video)
At the bottom of the page there is a numbered pagination.

However, I would like to make it so that on a mobile platform (android/iphone)
the user can paginate by swiping the pages to go forward or backward.

How do I adjust the pagination for a mobile platform?

Should I use a specific crossplatform tool like sencha to make this gallery?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you thought about using JQuery Mobile ?

http://jquerymobile.com/

Comment: yes. but cannot see a full code example for the swipe function